# In Jira, can I form a query to give me all tickets I touched yesterday

Tags: jira

In Jira, can I form a query to give me all tickets I touched yesterday

I can easily form a query to give me all tickets that were updated yesterday and that I touched at some point

but I would like to limit that 'at some point' to yesterday :)

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible (at this time) to query all types of activity on a ticket by a particular user, but if you're willing to settle for status changes, you could use something like:

`status changed BY username AFTER -1d`

You can replace username with currentuser() if you want this to be a query anyone can use without modification.

You can also broaden it with ORs and repeat the same logic with other fields, such as assignee, fixVersion, and so on. That would at least get you a query for all tickets where most standard fields had been changed by your username in the last day (-1d). For example:

`status changed BY currentuser() AFTER -1d OR fixVersion changed BY currentuser() AFTER -1d OR assignee changed BY currentuser() AFTER -1d`

And so on. Querying comment activity by username is (I'm 99% sure) impossible at this time, but there are open tickets in Atlassian's system for exactly this kind of searching, so we may get it some day.

Answer (score 2):

This should *hopefully* return all issues viewed on a specific day:

```
lastViewed = "YYYY/MM/DD"
```

For reference:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching+-+Fields+Reference#AdvancedSearching-FieldsReference-LastViewed

Comment: For a reusable query, you can replace a specific date with a relative one, such as "-1d" for one day ago.